# ¿Como interpretar un string como variable en django template?

Tags: python, django

Tengo lo siguiente en mis views de django con wagtail:

```
for cat in context["categories"]:     
        context[cat.slug] = ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public().filter(categories__slug = cat.slug).order_by("-date")
    
return context
```

Crea un contexto para que retorne los artículos de un blog según la categoría que corresponda, ahora, necesito imprimir cada uno de estos artículos según su categoría en mi template, pero necesito una forma de cambiar de variable conforme voy recorriendo mi ciclo for, he aquí lo que he intentado:

```
{% for cat in categories %}

      <h1>
          {{ cat.name }}
      </h1>

      {% for article in cat.slug %}

          <h1>
              {{ article.title }}
          </h1>

      {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Necesito realizarlo de esta manera especifica, puesto que luego hay que hacer arreglos que lo requieren, entre ellos, que el primer elemento del ciclo se renderice de cierta forma distinta al resto.

Lo que necesito es saber como hacer que "cat.slug" lo tome como la variable de contexto perteneciente a la categoría en cuestión, es decir, que si el valor de cat.slug sea "talento" entonces el for lo reconozca como la variable talento, no un string que contenga la palabra "talento", o alguna alternativa viable donde pueda utilizar más variables en el for.

Edit: He encontrado una respuesta, pero me gustaría saber si existen otras formas de realizar este proceso, publico la respuesta más abajo con detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Cree un array vacío e incluí las publicaciones del blog dentro de variables con el nombre de sus categorías, en lugar de directamente en el contexto, y luego con un append pude meter todas las variables dentro del array para pasarlo como contexto a mi view de django-wagtail, con ello el código del template acepta directamente los nombres dados por "cat.slug" como las variables almacenadas en el array "pub_by_cat", aquí los cambios que hice al código:

```
    pub_by_cat = []

    for cat in context["categories"]:     
        cat.slug = ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public().filter(categories__slug = cat.slug).order_by("-date")

        context[cat.slug] = cat.slug

        pub_by_cat.append(cat.slug)

    context["pub_by_cat"] = pub_by_cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estás haciendo un lío bastante grande.

Te recomiendo simplificar al máximo el código, en Python algo simple debe poderse crear con un código simple, nunca vas a necesitar mucha complejidad para hacer algo simple en Python/Django.

Nunca he usado Wagtail pero he montado varios blogs y CMS's en Django.
Puedes añadirle dinámicamente campos a los objetos (la magia de Python...), pero no pises campos que tienen un contenido con otro diferente.
Me refiero a que no debes guardar la consulta de ArticleDetailPage en cat.slug, sino en un campo nuevo:
pub_by_cat = []

```
for cat in context["categories"]:     
    cat.cat_articles = ArticleDetailPage.objects.live().public().filter(categories__slug = cat.slug).order_by("-date")
```

Luego en el template puedes usarlo así:

```
{% for cat in categories %}

  <h1>
      {{ cat.name }}
  </h1>

  {% for article in cat.cat_articles %}

      <h1>
          {{ article.title }}
      </h1>

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Por cierto, el slug te será útil para los enlaces, pero no lo modifiques dinámicamente.

No obstante, yo te recomendaría otro enfoque. Primero mírate bien la documentación o directamente el código de WagTail, seguramente Category ya haya una forma prevista para obtener los artículos live y public de una categoría. En caso de no haberlo, crearía una clase proxy de category y le añades los métodos que necesitara, pero dudo muchísimo que Wagtail no tenga ya un montón de funcionalidad para usar.